# Como usar o laravel guzzle para redirecionar um download de arquivo de uma requisição

Tags: laravel, libcurl, guzzle

Preciso da sua ajuda para encontrar uma maneira de ser um 'proxy' entre o frontend e um componente de software de terceiros usando o Laravel.

O software de terceiros está na rede da minha empresa e gera os arquivos sob demanda.
Por exemplo, se eu clicar em http://mycompany-third-party.com/12/csv, ele lerá os dados do banco de dados e os entregará para download como resposta (neste caso, um arquivo csv).

Mas não posso permitir que os usuários alcancem o ponto de extremidade de terceiros diretamente, então quero usar o laravel (guzzle) para solicitar o arquivo para terceiros e depois redirecionar para o cliente específico sem armazená-lo no meu disco local.

Como posso fazer algo assim usando laravel / guzzle ou outra biblioteca?

Esta é a maneira que tentei

```php
$response = Http::withOptions(['stream' => true])->withHeaders([
            'X-Metabase-Session' => $this->token,
       ])->post('http://mycompany-third-party.com/12/csv');

        $headers = $response->headers();

        return response($response->getBody())->withHeaders($headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Achei a solução. Temos que utilizar o [Streamed Downloads](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses).

Ta aqui para quem precisar.

```php
        $response = Http::withOptions(['stream' => true])->withHeaders([
            'X-Metabase-Session' => $this->token,
        ])->post(your-3th-url);


        return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($response) {
            echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
        }, 'fileName.extType');
```

Até mais.